# How defer Map value object creation when key is fetched

Tags: java, function, lambda

We had a factory method like below, which worked fine, but when the case statements increased, We had issues with SONAR.

```
class MessageFactory{
public Message create(int uuid) {
switch (uuid) {
  case FIRST_MESSAGE_ID:
    return new FirstMessage();
    .
  case SECOND_MESSAGE_ID:
    return new SecondMessage();
    .
  default:

      return null;
}}}

class Main{
MessageFactory factory = new MessageFactory();
Message message1=factory.get(FIRST_MESSAGE_ID); // needs a new instance everytime
.
.
MessageFactory factory = new MessageFactory();
Message message2=factory.get(FIRST_MESSAGE_ID); // needs a new instance everytime
}
```

To avoid the SONAR complaints we moved the object creation to a map.

```
public Message create(int uuid) {
Map<Integer, Message> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(FIRST_MESSAGE_ID, new FirstMessage());
.
.
.
map.put(SECOND_MESSAGE_ID, new SecondMessage());
}
if(map.containsKey(uuid)){
return map.get(uuid);
}
return null;
}
```

The only drawback of this is that every time when I try creating objects using create(int uuid), the whole "map" is initialized every time with all my 100+ objects.
Is there any way to defer creating objects only when the key is fetched? Or any other optimized way to solve this issue.

NOTE: I need a new instance of objects everytime
I cannot use a static map, as it will return the same object instance every time, instead of creating a new object for that key when asked for.

Can we use lambda functions here to fetch new object everytime only when the key is fetched?

Comment: Did you mean if `map.containsKey(uuid)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only drawback of this is that every time when I try creating objects using create(int uuid), the whole "map" is initialized every time with all my `100+` objects

Firstly, declare the *map* as a `static` field (*it seems like its contents is unrelated to a particular instance, if so it should be static*). It would be generated only once when the class gets loaded into memory.

Secondly, extract the logic responsible for initializing the *map* into a separate method.

> ***NOTE:*** I need a **new** instance of objects everytime

To meat this requirement, the `Map` should store not actual objects, but `Supplier`s for every kind of `Message`.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static final Map<Integer, Supplier<Message>> MESSAGE_BY_UUID = init();

public static Map<Integer, Supplier<Message>> init() {
    Map<Integer, Supplier<Message>> map = new HashMap<>();
    // your initialization logic
    map.put(FIRST_MESSAGE_ID, FirstMessage::new);
    map.put(SECOND_MESSAGE_ID, SecondMessage::new);
    ...
    return map;
}

public Message create(int uuid) {
    return MESSAGE_BY_UUID.get(uuid).get();
}
```

[*A simple Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tJA)

***Note*** that your `if-else` statement with `map.containsKey` check is redundant. Method `get()` would return `null` in case if provided *key* is not present in the map.

Spiking of other alternatives, the map can be initialized inline using method [`Map.ofEntries()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries(java.util.Map.Entry...)) which expects *varargs* of `Map.Entry` objects.

The downside of this approach is that it would be basically a `switch` in disguise, meaning that it would iterate over its *keys* in linear fashion. That's how it's implemented internally - it isn't hash-based, but maintains an array of alternating *keys* and *values*. With every invocation of the `get()` an immutable map returned by `Map.ofEntries()` would need to check up to `100+` UUID, in contrast with `HashMap` which would need to check only a couple (I said *couple* because collisions might occur).

Comment: the downside of having a static map is that it will return the same object instance every time, instead of creating a new object for that key when asked for. I need a new fresh instance everytime for a given key.

Comment: This is my factory class. So everytime when I try to create an object using this factory class, init will be invoked and it will initialize the map with all the 100+ objects , and then when I call create() for a specific key, it will give me an object and the map initialized will be available for gc.  So for each invocation of this class to get the object the map is initialized the the objects again..

Comment: @user2833621 Sure they would be garbigcollected. The thing is that it will slowdown the application - process of memory allocation is costful. It possible to achieve what you need - a **new** per every method invocation **without** creating a hundred of others. If you're interested, then tell how `FirstMessage()` and `SecondMessage()` differ, are they instances of different classes (and you have `100+` subclasses of `Message`) or they just receive some kind of unique argument?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247049/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-user2833621).

Comment: A simple Demo  link in your answers worked for my usecase. Thanks a lot for the help. This was superly helpful

Answer (score 2):

You may create a map of uuid to `Supplier` instead, so that you only need to create a readonly static unmodified map once. After geting the supplier by the uuid from the map you simply call the `get()` method to get a new instance. I think this matches the "defer creating object" you expect.

Supplier references:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html
- https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/supplier-interface-in-java-with-examples/amp/

Answer (score 0):

If there are fixed set of uuid and Message object pairs, make the Map a static final variable and move out of the method, instead of placing it inside method.
Like below:

```
class Main {
  static final Map<String, Message> messageMap = Map.of(
     FIRST_MESSAGE_ID, new FirstMessage(),
     .
     .
     .
     SECOND_MESSAGE_ID, new SecondMessage()
   );
}
```

usage:

```
Main.messageMap.get(uuid);
```

Comment: `Map.of` only supports `10` Key/Value pairs.

Comment: the downside of having a static map is that it will return the same object instance every time, instead of creating a new object for that key when asked for. I need a new fresh instance everytime for a given key.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will work for you:

- create an instance of the map but initialize it upon first call of `create()`.
- If the message isn't found, return a default message. This acts as a safeguard in cased you specify an incorrect `uuid`.
- This will work whether the map is declared static or not, but it does defer the creation as required.
- you can also move the creation code outside the `create()` method but it will be created when the class is initialized.

```
Map<Integer, Message> map = null;
public Message create(int uuid) {       
    if (map == null) {
         map = new HashMap<>();         
         map.put(FIRST_MESSAGE_ID, new FirstMessage());
         .
         map.put(SECOND_MESSAGE_ID, new SecondMessage());    
         ...     
     }
  
     return map.getOrDefault(uuid, someDefaultMessage);
}
```